# How to connect mobile phone to VS Code? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, mobile

On the advice of some of my friends, I want to connect my mobile phone to my computer for programming with Flutter
But I don't know how to do this?
If you have any information on this, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

If it is an android device just go to to developer setting and active usb debug mode and connect you device to your pc and good to go.

If it is an iOS device when you connect the device it ask you trust this computer and if you push trust button you good to go.

when you do this and connect your device you can select it from right bottom corner of vs code.

[image]

[image]

[image]